# How can i show the data from my request in my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, oop

So i have been working on a feature for my portfolio where the about me page is basicly a " document" with tabs and when you click on a tab the content that goes with that tab appears. The problem i am running into is that i dont know how to get the data from my php file into my html. So basicly i got the tabs working, i got the ajax working it reaches the php and the php gets the data from the database but then i dont know how to display this data. ill share my code:

HTML:

```
    <?php 
include 'includes/header.inc.php'; 

?>
<main>
  <section class="banner">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <article class="about-me">
          <div class="about-box">
            <div class="about-tabs">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab-about tab 1"><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                        <li class="tab-work tab 2"><a href="#">Work experience</a></li>
                        <li class="tab-school tab 3"><a href="#">Education</a></li>
                        <li class="tab-other tab 4"><a href="#">Other cetrificates</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="about-content">
              <div class="content-welcome">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Have a look around by clicking on the tabs! </p>
              </div>
              <div class="content-about"></div>
              <div class="content-work"></div>
              <divc class="content-school"></div>
              <div class="content-other"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
<?php include 'includes/sidebarnav.inc.php'; ?>
<script src="js/abouttabs.js"> </script>
</main>
<?php include 'includes/footer.inc.php'; ?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    let activeTab ='';
    let tabNum = '';
    $(".tab-about").click(function() {
        if (activeTab == '') {
            $(".tab-about").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "about";
            return activeTab;
        } else {
            $(".active").removeClass('active');
            $(".tab-about").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "about";
            return activeTab;
        }
    });
    $(".tab-work").click(function() {
        if (activeTab == '') {
            $(".tab-work").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "work";
            return activeTab;
        } else {
            $(".active").removeClass('active');
            $(".tab-work").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "work";
            return activeTab;
        }
    });
    $(".tab-school").click(function() {

        if (activeTab == '') {
            $(".tab-school").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "school";
            return activeTab;
        } else {
            $(".active").removeClass('active');
            $(".tab-school").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "school";
            return activeTab;
        }
    });
    $(".tab-other").click(function() {
        if (activeTab == '') {
            $(".tab-other").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "other";
            return activeTab;
        } else {
            $(".active").removeClass('active');
            $(".tab-other").addClass('active');
            activeTab = "other";
            return activeTab;
        }
    });

    $('.about-tabs li').click(function(){
       
        switch (activeTab) {
            case 'about':
                tabNum = 1;
                
                break;
            case 'work':
                console.log('work');
                tabNum = 2;
                break;
            case 'school':
                console.log('school');
                tabNum = 3;
                break;
            case 'other':
                console.log('other');
                 tabNum = 4;
                break;
            default:
                console.log('oopsie');
                
                break;
        }
    });
    $('.tab').click(function(){
        let tab = tabNum;


        console.log(tab);
      
        jQuery.ajax({
              url: "testdit.php",
              type : "POST",
              data:{tab:tab},
              success:function(data){
                  
                 
                  console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(error)
              {
                  alert("couldnt be sent" + error); 
              }
          }); 
      });     
   
});
```

php :

so this is my db query class :

```
<?php
require_once 'dbh.class.php';
 class QueryDatabase extends Database {



  public function getData($tablename, $selector, $value) {

    if (!isset($selector)){
        echo 'Something went wrong!';
    } else if ($selector == ''){
      $stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        return $row;
      }
    }else {
      $stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $tablename where $selector = $value");
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        return $row;
      }
    }
    }


  public function setData($tablename, $colums, $data) {
    if (!isset($tablename) or !isset($data)) {
      echo 'Something went wrong!';
    } else {
      $sql  = "INSERT INTO $tablename";
      $sql .= $colums;
      $sql .= $data;
      $q = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
      $q->execute();
    }

  }
  protected function changeData() {

  }
  protected function delData() {

  }
}
```

this is my about page class :

```
<?php 

class About {

    public $activeTab = '';
    public $pageData = '';

    public function setTab($tab) {
        $this->activeTab = $tab;
    }
    
    public function getPage() {
        // vraag de content van de tab uit de database
        $getPageContent = new QueryDatabase();
        $this->pageData = $getPageContent->getData('about_page_content','tab',$this->activeTab);
       
        
        
    }   
   
}
```

and this is my php file that actually handles the ajax request:

```
<?php
  include 'classes\dbh.class.php';
  include 'classes\querydatabase.class.php';
  include 'classes\about.class.php';

$tab = $_POST['tab'];
$try = new About();
$try->setTab($tab);
$try->getPage();
extract($try->pageData, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

echo $title;


exit;
```

so i get the data from the extract and when i echo $title for example i get the right data but i dont know how to use this in my about page html

i hope i explained this correctly, i am not quite sure how else to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following updates to accomplish this:

**Give each tab data attribute for the target:**

```
<li data-target=".content-about" class="tab-about tab 1"><a href="#">About me</a></li>
<li data-target=".content-work" class="tab-work tab 2"><a href="#">Work experience</a></li>
<li data-target=".content-school" class="tab-school tab 3"><a href="#">Education</a></li>
<li data-target=".content-other" class="tab-other tab 4"><a href="#">Other cetrificates</a></li>
```

**take out the random C after div as shown below:**

```
<divc class="content-school"></div>
```

**For the event listener get the target**
Also you will want to remove ALL of your click handlers except for the one called by `.tab`. You essentially have 3 click handlers for EACH tab, that will mess things up.

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
  _target = $(this).data("target");
  $('.tab.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
```

**in the success function refer to _target**

```
$(_target).html(data);
```

Comment: thank you im going to try that! Good catch on the random c btw lol didnt notice that one. Edit: alright so i tried it and tried to console.log _target but it is undefined

Comment: @FlorisKroeze, I updated my answer for the click handler.

Comment: i saw! it still says it is undefined thanks for cleaning up my code by the way didnt realise it could have been so short haha edit: nevermind im just too tired to code atm i think. i added the data-target to the content div's your code works great!